# Why do you need to put 'pd.Series =' when making a change in the pd.Series

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering why I need to say `pd.Series =` when using for instance  `pd.Series.str.replace`

```
test = pd.Series(['T1 in A','T1 in B','T1 in C'])
test.str.replace('in', 'out')
print(test)
```

output is given below, where 'in' is not replaced with 'out'

```
0    T1 in A
1    T1 in B
2    T1 in C
```

when I say `test = test.str.replace('in', 'out')` instead of only `test.str.replace('in', 'out')` the output is correct:

```
0    T1 out A
1    T1 out B
2    T1 out C
```

Comment: It's because you're using the `Series` class methods which can only be accessed by calling it

Comment: The return of `Series.str.replace` is "a **copy** of the object". Without assigning it back you've done the manipulation but then you just throw away the result.